# What is the default seed for Powershell Get-Random cmdlet

Tags: powershell, random

The documentation for the Powershell `Get-Random` cmdlet suggests that the seed is the system tick count but, if the following test is performed, the value of `$rand1` is not replicated in the output of the `for()` loop and so appears to be independent of `TickCount`. Why is this so?

```
# generate a random int32 - should automatically use the tickcount as seed?
$tick1 = ([Environment]::TickCount)
$rand1 = Get-Random
Write-Host $rand1
$tick2 = ([Environment]::TickCount)

# generate seeded randoms with all possible values used to generate $rand1
for ($i = $tick1; $i -le $tick2; $i++) {
    $rand2 = Get-Random -SetSeed $i
    Write-Host $rand2
}
```

Comment: 2 things: The `TickCount` value undoubtedly increased in the time between assigning the current tick count to `$tick1` and resolving + executing `Get-Random`. Additionally, the help file says that it *uses* the system clock to calculate the seed, not that the seed *is* the value of the system clock, necessarily

Comment: Regarding the first point: that's why I collected a prior and post tick count ($tick1 and $tick2) and then looped over all possible values which were available to Get-Random at the time that $rand1 is generated, so I think that's accounted for?

And oddly enough Get-Random is simply a wrapper for the .net Random function. I have tested that function and it does work exactly as expected - it genuinely does use the tick count.

Comment: You're right - there must be something extra going on in the PowerShell cmdlet, but when examining it using powershell reflector I can't see that it's doing anything other than calling and passing on the .net generator. It's a bit obscure.

Comment: If you open ILSpy and compare the `Random` class in mscorlib and `GetRandomCommand` in Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility, you'll find that `GetRandomCommand` does *not* wrap `Random`, but initializes it's own `RandomNumberGenerator`, bypassing the `Random(Environment.TickCount)` initialization that you'd expect from `Random` altogether

Comment: That's really useful Mathias - thanks, I've been looking at the cmdlet using Reflector but have just had a look using ILSpy too - I can't see a definition for RandomNumberGenereator though - it just appears that GetRandomCommand is calling Random in the BeginProcessing() function?

Comment: Load mscorlib into ILSpy and it should be able to resolve the references. Might be different for newer versions of PowerShell

Answer (score 3):

`Get-Random` isn't necessarily seeded directly when you use it (certainly not every time you use it), it could be either at process startup, or when you first use it in a session. PRNGs shouldn't be seeded more than once, usually.

Also, as Mathias notes in a comment, it doesn't necessarily use the value of `Environment.TickCount` directly. You could use ILSpy to look at the source of the relevant assembly to find out how exactly it's done. I won't do that for you since I'm a contributor to an open-source PowerShell implementation.

Answer (score 2):

So, I was curious about this today and now that PowerShell is open source I thought I'd just go look at the [source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/GetRandomCommand.cs)...

Get-Random does not use `[Environment]::TickCount` as the seed. In fact the only time it doesn't use `[System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator]::Create()` is when you manually specify a seed.

It has 2 constructors...

```
internal class PolymorphicRandomNumberGenerator
{
    public PolymorphicRandomNumberGenerator()
    {
        _cryptographicGenerator = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
        _pseudoGenerator = null;
    }

    internal PolymorphicRandomNumberGenerator(int seed)
    {
        _cryptographicGenerator = null;
        _pseudoGenerator = new Random(seed);
    }
    ...
```

It only calls the constructor with a seed if SetSeed has a value in the Begin process:

```
/// <summary>
/// This method implements the BeginProcessing method for get-random command.
/// </summary>
protected override void BeginProcessing()
{
    if (SetSeed.HasValue)
    {
        Generator = new PolymorphicRandomNumberGenerator(SetSeed.Value);
    }
    ...
```

That would set `_pseudoGenerator` using `System.Random`

Otherwise it only ever calls the public constructor without a seed...which sets `_cryptographicGenerator` using `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator`